# Jetpack compose layout is not responsive across different phone screen sizes

Tags: responsive-design, android-jetpack-compose

I have designed a screen and tested it on Pixel 5a screen, Everything fits well in the screen. But testing the same app on a Nokia phone, the button got bigger, margins are bigger,
Nothing is scaling. I used to use the sdp library in xml, There is also same library for jetpack compose [SDP-Compose](https://androidexample365.com/sdp-compose-a-scalable-size-unit-for-jetpack-compose/).
But this library also not seems to work in my case.
What is the best approach to make layouts responsive across different mobile screen sizes. I don't need it for tablet or any other device. Just for Phones.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this you need to know that latest phones nowadays are using much higher DPI from 320-480 dpi,

To preserve the visible size of your UI on screens with different densities, you must design your UI using density-independent pixels (dp) as your unit of measurement. One dp is a virtual pixel unit that's roughly equal to one pixel on a medium-density screen (160dpi; the "baseline" density). Android translates this value to the appropriate number of real pixels for each other density.

For example, consider the two devices in figure 1. If you were to define a view to be "100px" wide, it will appear much larger on the device on the left. So you must instead use "100dp" to ensure it appears the same size on both screens.

When defining text sizes, however, you should instead use scalable pixels (sp) as your units (but never use sp for layout sizes). The sp unit is the same size as dp, by default, but it resizes based on the user's preferred text size.

my first solution would be to use DP values instead of using px values. and if you are using dp values try using constrain layout for regular XML, if you are using Compose try using fractional Values.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **SDP** and **SSP** from **intuit library** in compose too
by
`dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._16sdp)`
`dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._16ssp).value.sp`